# How to prove this relation between definite integral and the sum of definite integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, laplace-transform, periodic-functions

When there is a periodic function $f:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ with a period of $M>0$. How can I prove the following equality (assuming that the integral exists of course):

> $$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\int_{pM}^{(p+1)M}f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought the fact that the function is periodic would eliminate the possibility of the limit existing.

Comment: I don't think that this integral exists if $f(t)$ is not constantly $0$.

Comment: @SMM Now it can exists :)

Comment: If the LHS is understood in improper integral sense, then $$\text{[LHS]}=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{0}^{a}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt$$where hte limit ls along real numbers. On the other hand,$$\text{[RHS]}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{nM}f(t)e^{-st}\,dt$$where the limit is along integers. Thus knowing that the LHS converges, the RHS also converges to the same value.

Comment: is $s$ a positive real?

Comment: @JorgeFernández No $s\in\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

Is this very naive calculation
of any use?

If
$ |\int_0^M f(t)e^{-st}dt|
\le V
$
is bounded,
then

$\begin{array}\\
|\int_{pM}^{p(M+1)} f(t)e^{-st}dt|
&=|\int_{0}^{M} f(t+pM)e^{-s(t+pM)}dt|\\
&=|e^{-spM}\int_{0}^{M} f(t)e^{-st}dt|\\
&\le|e^{-spM}V|\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } p \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{p=P}^{\infty}\int_{pM}^{p(M+1)} f(t)e^{-st}dt|
&\le\sum_{p=P}^{\infty}|e^{-spM}V|\\
&=\dfrac{Ve^{-sPM}}{1-e^{-sM}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{nM} f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\int_{pM}^{(p+1)M}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{M}f(t+pM)e^{-s(t+pM)}dt\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} e^{-spM}\int_{0}^{M}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1-e^{-sMn}}{1-e^{-sM}}\int_{0}^{M}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{1-e^{-sM}}\int_{0}^{M}f(t)e^{-st}dt\\
\end{array}
$